# Galeria com filtro de categoria

Tags: javascript, css, front-end, framework, carousel

preciso implementar o seguinte:
botões de categoria + galeria da categoria

Tenho várias categorias no meu site e uma galeria de imagens para cada uma. No front, vou criar botões com as categorias e logo abaixo um *slider*.

Preciso que ao clicar em um botão de categoria, fique no slider, somente as imagens referente aquela categoria.

Ps: ignorem o botão 'todas' porque não vai ter

Seguem os códigos que já tenho:

```js
$("#Glide").glide({
    type: "carousel",
    autoplay: 0
});

$(".filter-button").click(function () {
    var value = $(this).attr('data-filter');

    if (value == "all") {
        $('.filter').show();
    }
    else {
        $(".filter").not('.' + value).hide();
        $('.filter').filter('.' + value).show();

    }
});
```

```css
.glide {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/glidejs@2.1.0/dist/css/glide.core.css">        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/glidejs@2.1.0/dist/css/glide.theme.css">        
    <title>Gallery Filter By Category</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div align="center">
        <button class="filter-button" data-filter="all">All</button>
        <button class="filter-button" data-filter="c1">Category 1</button>
        <button class="filter-button" data-filter="c2">Category 2</button>
        <button class="filter-button" data-filter="c3">Category 3</button>
        <button class="filter-button" data-filter="c4">Category 4</button>
    </div>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <div id="Glide" class="glide">

        <div class="glide__arrows">
            <button class="glide__arrow prev" data-glide-dir="<">prev</button>
            <button class="glide__arrow next" data-glide-dir=">">next</button>
        </div>

        <div class="glide__wrapper">
            <ul class="glide__track">
                <li class="glide__slide filter c1">
                    <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/300x300/a4c400/?text=category1&font=lobster&font_size=55">
                </li>
                <li class="glide__slide filter c3">
                    <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/300x300/0050ef/?text=category3&font=lobster&font_size=55">
                </li>
                <li class="glide__slide filter c1">
                    <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/300x300/a4c400/?text=category1&font=lobster&font_size=55">
                </li>
                <li class="glide__slide filter c2">
                    <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/300x300/00aba9/?text=category2&font=lobster&font_size=55">
                </li>
                <li class="glide__slide filter c3">
                    <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/300x300/0050ef/?text=category3&font=lobster&font_size=55">
                </li>
                <li class="glide__slide filter c4">
                    <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/300x300/d80073/?text=category4&font=lobster&font_size=55">
                </li>
                <li class="glide__slide filter c2">
                    <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/300x300/00aba9/?text=category2&font=lobster&font_size=55">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/glidejs@2.1.0/dist/glide.js"></script>    
    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Você vai carregar todas as imagens de uma vez e depois filtrar, ou vai trocar o conteúdo da galeria ao clicar nos botões? Dê uma olhada [nesse link](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/portfolio-gallery-with-filtering-category) ver se é mais ou menos a idéia.

Comment: R: é mais ou menos isso, porém no caso desse exemplo, ele troca imagens soltas, eu preciso que o meu funcione dentro do 'slider' o problema é acertar o javascript para o slider funcionar

Comment: Se juntar a ideia [deste aqui](https://codepen.io/redfrost/pen/mzHjb) com a lógica de filtro do outro acredito que seja o ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode ter um array de objetos destas imagens, e conforme for alterando as galerias, ir mapeando esse array e injetando os elementos de acordo com sua quantidade. Desta forma você teria uma página mais dinâmica e indiferentemente do tamanho da galeria ela sempre seria renderizada sem muita alteração no código.
Ou você pode simplesmente guardar os valores das tags img, e ir substituindo o atributo delas, realizando a limpeza dos atributos quando necessário.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("img").map(function(item){ 
    item.setAttribute("src","novo valor")
})
```

Esta seria uma forma de alterar o atributo sem injetar elementos, caso queira injetar elementos no DOM, é algo neste sentido:

```
    var arrayImages = ["img1.jpg","img2.jpg","img3.jpg","img4.jpg"]
    var galeria = document.getElementById("galeriaId")
    var arrayElementImages = []
    for(var i = 0; i < arrayImages.length; i++){
        var imgContainer = document.createElement("div")
        var imgElement = document.createElement("img")
        imgElement.setAttribute("src", arrayImages[i])
        imgContainer.appendChild(imgElement)
        galeria.appendChild(imgContainer)
    }
```

Somente ressalto que injetar elementos no DOM é algo pesado de se fazer o tempo todo, ainda mais se sua página carrega muito conteúdo.

Este seria uma caminho para sua solução, uma outra saída é ter todo o conteúdo da página carregado e ir alterando o display para none/block de cada galeria. Depende do que melhor lhe convir.

Comment: Segue um exemplo parecido: https://jsfiddle.net/tetbdkpe/